# Laravel display view in modal window

Tags: laravel

thank you for your time, 
i have a problem with a laravel app
there is a table with data, and for each row there is a details button linked to a controller action that returns the detailed data in a modal window.

here is a button code

```
<button data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('surveys.show',$sitedata->id)}}" data-target="#myModal">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
                  </button>
```

here is the controller code

```
public function show($id) 
{        
    $selectedSurveys = Survey::find($id)->where('site_data_id', $id)->get();

    return view('modals/survey-details')->with('selectedSurveys', $selectedSurveys);
}
```

here is the route

```
 Route::get('/surveys/{id}', 'SurveysController@show')->name('surveys.show');
```

here is the view  modals/survey-details

```
<div class="modal-body">                        
<div class="box-body table-responsive">            
    <table class="table table-hover center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Response 1</th>
                <th>Response 2</th> 
                <th>Response 3</th>
                <th>Sent At</th>
                <th>Completed At</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($selectedSurveys as $ss)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$ss->email}}</td> 
                <td>{{$ss->grade1}}</td>
                <td>{{$ss->grade2}}</td>
                <td>{{$ss->grade3}}</td>
                <td>{{$ss->created_at->format('d-M-Y ')}}</td>
                <td>@if(empty ($ss->updated_at))
                        Not Completed                   
                    @else
                        {{$ss->updated_at->format('d-M-Y ')}}                 
                    @endif
                </td>         
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

index.blade table

```
<table class="table table-hover center" id="table_id">

                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Studio</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Satisfied Survey</th>
                    <th>SOS Reponse</th>  
                    <th>Ticket Management Quality</th>                       
                    <th>User Face to Face Survey</th>
                    <th>Opened</th>
                    <th>Closed</th>   
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>  
                    <th>Opened by</th>
                    <th>Updated by</th>           
                  </tr>                    
                </thead>
                <tbody>              
                  @foreach($sitesdata as $sitedata)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{$sitedata->site->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sitedata->month}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sitedata->year}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sitedata->satisfaction}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sitedata->response}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sitedata->management}}</td>     
                    <td>{{$sitedata->survey}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sitedata->opened}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sitedata->closed}}</td>       
                    <td>{{$sitedata->active}}</td> 
                    <td data-id="{{$sitedata->id}}" data-user="{{auth()->user()->id}}">
                      <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                      @if(in_array($sitedata->id, $sentSurveys))                      
                      <button data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('surveys.show',$sitedata->id)}}" data-target="#myModal">
                        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
                      </button>   

                      @else
                      <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#send-mail" class="btn btn-primary send-mail"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></button>
                      @endif
                    </td>                  
                    <td>{{$sitedata->user->name}}<br>{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($sitedata->created_at)->format('d.m.Y H.i')}}</td>
                    @if($sitedata->modified_by != null)
                    <td>{{$users->firstWhere('id', $sitedata->modified_by)->name}}<br>{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($sitedata->updated_at)->format('d.m.Y H.i')}}</td> 
                    @else 
                    <td>Not updated yet</td> 
                    @endif                 
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Studio</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
```

The button works, it gets the data and displays it in the modal, but when i click the button on another row it show the data from the first row.

In laravel telescope i get only 1 request to SurveysController@show even if i press all the buttons, to get new data i have to reload the page

Please help, i have no idea what to try

Comment: Your modal need to update when you click the row. Since it's not dynamic. Better show your full HTML.

Comment: added the table code, how can i make the modal dynamic, maybe give some pointer on how to achieve this?

Comment: @RobertB use jquery ajax for this purpose

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content May assit with you using jQuery and Ajax to change the modal content. It would be easier this way.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas, went with loading the view with ajax when the modal was opened. You ideas gave me a starting point for more research. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Vue you can add method @click to row

```html
<td @click="showModal(sitedata)">
```

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            modalData: false,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        showModal(sitedata) {
           this.modalData = sitedata
           $('#yourModalId').modal('show');
        }
    }
}
```